# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" (parsing)

Tags: java, android, parsing

The listed error occurs to this: (just a basic calorie calculator- enter #s in it updates the TextView of calorieTotal)((It might be better served with a button?))

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText breakfastCals;
EditText lunchCals;
EditText dinnerCals;
EditText otherCals;
EditText burnedCals;
TextView calorieTotal;

int n1=0;
int n2=0;
int n3=0;
int n4=0;
int n5=0;
int total=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    breakfastCals = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.breakfastCals);
    n1= Integer.parseInt(breakfastCals.getText().toString());

    lunchCals = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lunchCals);
    n2= Integer.parseInt(lunchCals.getText().toString());

    dinnerCals = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dinnerCals);
    n3= Integer.parseInt(dinnerCals.getText().toString());

    otherCals = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.otherCals);
    n4= Integer.parseInt(otherCals.getText().toString());

    burnedCals = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.burnedCals);
    n5= Integer.parseInt(burnedCals.getText().toString());

    total=((1500-n1-n2-n3-n4)+n5);
    calorieTotal= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calorieTotal);
    calorieTotal.setText(Integer.toString(total));

}
```

Comment: Perhaps some checks that the user actually entered a number might help rather than crashing with a runtime error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to validate user input JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145728/best-way-to-validate-user-input-jdbc)

Answer (score 0):

make your editText as a numberic, to avoid invalid input and accept only numbers

add `android:inputType="number"` at the xml attributes.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myNumber"
android:digits="0123456789."
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your layout xml, add given code to all edittext, in which you want only number

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

it will allows your edittext for only number,
so NumberFormatException will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Before parsing into integer add a condition whether value is empty or not

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(breakfastCals.getText().toString()) {
n1=0;
}else{

n1= Integer.parseInt(breakfastCals.getText().toString()); 
}
```

Do this for all edittext